# from tensorflow.compat.v1 import estimator as tf_estimator ImportError: cannot import name 'estimator' from 'tensorflow.compat.v1'

Tags: object-detection, real-time, raspberry-pi4, tensorflow-estimator

I'm doing an object detection project on the raspi-5 and i run this code on the cmd line

python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000

However, I encounter this error:
pi@pi:~/Desktop/RealTimeObjectDetection $ python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/RealTimeObjectDetection/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 31, in 
from object_detection import model_lib_v2
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.11.egg/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in 
from object_detection import inputs
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.11.egg/object_detection/inputs.py", line 24, in 
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import estimator as tf_estimator
ImportError: **cannot import name 'estimator' from 'tensorflow.compat.v1' **(/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/**init**.py)

Need some advice on what to do to fix it

I tried downgrading the version for Tensorflow

Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.15.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: tensorflow-cpu-aws
Required-by: tf-models-official

and im running on Python 3.11

Answer (score 0):

**This is not my answer but it worked for me.**

Recently, Google Colab updated its TensorFlow version from 2.15.0 to 2.16.1. Try reinstalling TensorFlow using the following commands:

!pip uninstall tensorflow --y

!pip install tensorflow==2.15.0

then restart runtime when asked in colab. You should be able to import the correct version of TensorFlow.

Source = https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/63618